# Tree with a size greater than n -1

Tags: graph-theory

I have a problem asking:

A tree of order $35$ is know to have $25$ vertices of deg $1$, $2$ vertices of deg $2$, $3$ vertices of deg $4$, one vertex of deg $5$, and $2$ vertices of deg $6$, and $2$ vertices of the same unknown deg $x$. What is $x$?

Since every tree of order $n$ has a size of $n-1$

$$35 - 1 = 58 + 2x$$ ?

I obtained $58$ by adding the degrees of all the given vertices. The stated equality can never be satisfied with a positive $x$. How is this a possible graph of a tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the degrees of all the vertices together, you end up counting each edge twice: an edge $vw$ contributes $1$ to the degree of $v$ and $1$ to the degree of $w$.

So if your tree has $35$ vertices (and therefore $34$ edges) the sum of all degrees should be $34 \cdot 2 = 68$.

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is of order 35 then it has size 34, as you stated the size of any tree of order n is n-1. 
The First Theorem of Graph Theory tells us that the summation of all the degrees of a graph of size m is 2m. So all of the degrees in your graph should add up to 68. 2m or 2x34 = 68.
When you add up all the degrees that you are given for your graph you get 58, which means x=5.